# Possible to include sets in a PostgreSQL IN clause?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that does something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
(a, b) in ((23, [1]), (20, [0]), (17, [-1, 0, 1]), (55, [-1, 0]);
```

The result set would be (assuming the items existed!):

```
23, 1
20, 0
17, -1 (could have also been 17, 0 or 17,1)
55, -1 (could have also been 55, 0)
```

That is, the set items are like OR clauses. "We insist that (a, b) include (23, 1) and (20, 0), but 17 can either be -1, 0, or 1." Does that make sense?

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `= ANY`:

```
WITH cte(i, list) AS (
  VALUES (23, ARRAY[1]),(20, ARRAY[0]),(17, ARRAY[-1,0,1]), (55, ARRAY[-1, 0])
)
SELECT t.*
FROM tab t
JOIN cte c ON t.a = c.i AND t.b = ANY(list);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=46cd0036fe1893d76ee6ec5f67dd4600)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (a, b) IN (VALUES (23, ARRAY[1]),(20, ARRAY[0]),(17, ARRAY[-1,0,1]),(55, ARRAY[-1, 0]))
```

[VALUES CLAUSE POSTGRESQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html)

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but I'm getting this error on my end: `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]`